# unix, adding users to existing directory in centos

Tags: linux, centos, users, home, useradd

I'm trying to add users to an existing directory but I keep getting:

> useradd: warning: the home directory already exists. Not copying any file from skel directory into it.

I want to add users to the `/home/test` directory; I know this isn't a good thing to do and there are many reasons why I shouldn't do it, but I need to do it anyway.

I want to add the user `alex` to the existing directory and `ralf`, so I tried to change the permission of the folders so users can access it:

```
chmod -R 777 /home/test
```

And add the user to the folder:

```
useradd -m -d /home/test ralf
```

But when I try to switch to the new user it shows this:

[image]

I think it is a permission issue but I am not too sure.

Comment: What is the reason beyond this? Which result do you want to accomplish? It looks like you're trying to break the system, which is never a wise thing to do (unless for testing).

Answer (score -2):

From `useradd(8)`:

```
-M, --no-create-home

Do no create the user's home directory, even if the system wide setting
from /etc/login.defs (CREATE_HOME) is set to yes.
```